# .NET core Web API: Get currently logged in user outside of controller - Database First approach

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to get the currently logged in user for audit logging outside of a controller.
I use **Database First approach** in a .NET core 3.1 API project.
Which is why I created a new context class which derives from MyContext class to handle the audit. In here I now want to get the user information. 
I use JWT Claim based authentication.

In below class "**MyNewContext**", I added *IHttpContextAccessor* to the Startup.cs (`services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`) to use it in "**MyNewContext**" class however User or Claims objects are emtpy when the constructor is called.

I can only seem to get the User object when IHttpContextAccessor is used inside a controller. Also if I create a service class for IHttpContextAccessor it only has the user object when called inside a controller.

```
public class MyNewContext : MyContext
{
    private static string _userGuid;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyNewContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        GetUserGuid();
    }

    public void GetUserGuid()
    {
        _userGuid = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst("unique_name")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddDbContext<MyNewContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:xyz"]));
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to get the user information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my startup.cs I have the AddJwtBearer functionality.

In there I now just pass the guidClaim value to the SetGuid function in MyNewContext. No need for IHttpContextAccessor.

```
Claim guidClaim = (context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("unique_name");

MyNewContext.SetGuid(guidClaim.Value);
```

This works for me - for now.